# Framework for Unit Testing in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am relatively new to Android. My experience in testing isn't too deep either. I am looking for a unit test framework for Android.

Please tell me what framework you suggest with respect to:

- Simplicity of implementing tests
- Supporting community and tools
- Compatibility with application certification processes
- Integration with IDEs (Eclipse)
- Other aspects you find important...

Comment: Hope this link helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/), it works quite well. If you've used Selenium, some aspects should be familiar.