# Looking for functional GUI testing tool for Android without code access

Tags: android, functional-testing, robotium

I'm looking for a functional GUI testing tool for Android without the base of source code. Most things I found are JUnit testing frameworks that extend the `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity>` from Android SDK.
But I look for a tool that provides f. exe. button clicks, enter String to txt fields and so on without knowing the Activity class name, package or further information.

Perfect would be something that finds Widgets on a already started Android app, can interact with it from an other application without the information I told above.
I was having a look at Robotium RC, but found no information, tutorials etc. just the JavaDoc and the `.jar` file.

edit: It should be open source

Comment: Have you tried [Robotium](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8936437/996493) ?

Comment: Yes I looked at the sample code. The bad thing about Robotium for me is, that I wanted to avoid creating an Android jUnit testing project for each AUT and with Robotium I need to do this and (also for the blackbox testing feature) I need to have the name of the startActivity and the package name. Are there any frameworks that have that feature?

Comment: The only alternative i know is http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/

Comment: I forgot to say, that it should be openSource. Added it to the topic-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at the standard [monkeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) android tool. With the help of this tool you can start your application, emulate drag gestures, press on buttons, tap on the screen. To automate the process of creation of these scripts you can use `monkeyrecorder.py` script.

Comment: It looks pretty like what I'm looking for except that I have to know the package and activity name. I'll try it soon. Is it possible to span test cases over multiple activities?

Comment: You can reproduce steps without knowing the name of the package. Just install an application, check where it is in the launcher list and record steps of tapping on the icon of this application. >> Is it possible to span test cases over multiple activities? I did not understand this question. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: Thanks, that's the best solution. According to your question: i meant because I don't want to access the app from outside of other android testing projects. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try bot-bot. Following is the link:

http://imaginea.github.com/bot-bot/

It can integrate itself with an apk. It works best if you have the source code of the app under test.